# Whats the best way in Swift to animate an array of NSViews to appear one after another in an NSStackView?

Tags: swift, macos, animation, nsstackview, nsanimationcontext

I'm able add a number of NSTextFields to an NSStackView using the following code:

`optionsStackView.addView(newOption, in: .center)`

The problem I'm encountering is getting each NSTextField (newOption) to appear one after another when the view appears - not all at once when using NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in }

```
        let stackViewSubViews = optionsStackView?.arrangedSubviews.enumerated()
        stackViewSubViews!.forEach({ newOption in
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
                context.duration = 1
                newOption.element.animator().alphaValue = 1
            }
        })
```

I basically need to *delay* for a half a second each time the for loop runs to show one NSTextField after another for all the NSTextFields but I can't quite figure out how to do this. I looked at using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5)` but can't quite figure out the code to make this work without everything appearing all at once...

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to insert a delay during each iteration of a loop is to turn the loop into a recursion. I'll show you the general technique and you can adapt it to your use case:

```
func slowly(from i:Int, to n:Int) {
    print(i)
    if i != n {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now()+0.5) {
            slowly(from:i+1, to:n)
        }
    }
}
slowly(from:1, to:3)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt this worked perfectly for my needs. 